# Why are there duplicate products exported with a different store view?

Tags: magento2, product, import, importexport

Why are duplicate **product** entries are exported from a magento 2 install that's data was migrated from magento 1?

The duplicate entries of **products** don't have names and some other attributes but they have a `store_view_code`.

The correct **products**, with all attributes don't have a `store_view_code` set. Probably global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Magento 2** considers single product as multiple products on the basis of it's `store_view_code`.

For example let's assume you are having two stores in **Magento** on the basis of languages let's suppose store with English language has `store_view_code`= `en` & store with Spanish language has `store_view_code` = `es` so **Magento** will have three entries of your products with three different `store_view_code`

1. Entry with blank `store_view_code` that is your default product entry.
2. Entry with `store_view_code = en` that is the product entry for your English store.
3. Entry with `store_view_code = es` that is the product entry for your English store.

It is use full to have this different entries for the different **store_view** because with the help of this you can have different name of your single product as per the language of your store. You can add different **meta-key-words** & **meta-description** to make your product & website **S.E.O.** friendly & you also can have different images for your product as `base, thumbnail, swatches` image.